# Is it possible to run Drush 8 smoothly on WSL?

Tags: drush

Can WSL be used to run Drush 8 smoothly? I am asking because Drush 8/master doesn't run smooth on a Windows machine.

Until now, I ran Drush 8/master on an Ubuntu virtual machine. I wonder if it's possible to run it on Windows 10 using WSL.

With my very basic knowledge of Operating Systems, I can't strictly determine if having Bash and Ubuntu binaries in Windows is actually enough to run Drush or if something extra which hasn't been released is needed.
I don't know also how to integrate WSL with WAMP/Xampp ,as well as with the *c:/drush* folder, or how to make some environment variable would be enough.

Answer (score 4):

We haven't tried this yet. Please give it a spin, and report your results in the [issue queue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues).

Note also that if you want the dev branch of Drush 8, you should use the `8.x` branch.  The `master` branch is now Drush 9.